# Llamar evento click con jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de llamar al evento click con jquery, asi tengo mi codigo html.

```js
$('#cargar').click(function(){
  alert("hola");
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Autorizar!" id="cargar">https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Aqui funciona perfecto el evento, pero en mi documento no, ya que ese botón lo genero por medio de un documento de php, influye que el botón es generado después de que se carga el css???

Comment: El CSS no tiene que ver, por otro lado ¿en qué orden llamas al archivo donde se genera el botón y el archivo js que lee el evento click?

Comment: Ese boton se genera despues de que cambia un select y el css lo llamo al momento de cargar la pagina @BetaM

Comment: ¿Obtienes en consola algún error que puedas añadir a tu pregunta?

Comment: Ningún error @BetaM

Comment: @BetaM ya lo pude solucionar: $('#informe').on("click", '#cargar', function(){
  alert("hola");
  
 }); , $('#informe') es un div donde poso mi tabla después de crearla, buscando un poco encontre esta solucion y me funciono, gracias por tu interes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no funciona porque estás cargando primero el script y después el HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#cargar').click(function(){
  alert("hola");
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="Autorizar!" id="cargar">
```

En este otro, se carga el script después del HTML y sí funciona

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Autorizar!" id="cargar">
<script>
$('#cargar').click(function(){
  alert("hola");
});
</script>
```

Si tus scripts están en un archivo externo, coloca la etiqueta `<script src="..."></script>` hasta abajo, antes de `</body>` o usa una función para que los scripts se ejecuten después de cargar el HTML:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() { // <-- Esto hace que se ejecute el código hasta que se cargó el DOM
    $('#cargar').click(function(){
      alert("hola");
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="Autorizar!" id="cargar">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respues @Triby, eso supuse cuando escribí la pregunta, la solucion que encontre fue esta: $('#informe').on("click", '#cargar', function(){
  alert("hola");
  
 }); y me funciono ya que $('#informe') es un div donde cargo la tabla le asigne de manera virtual el evento click a ese elemento y le dije que no mas cargue el boton sea el boton que reciba el evento click y me funciono perfecto.